# how to select and join same table in mssql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My data table structure is as below

```
UserID   Name     upline
--------------------------- 
1        John     0 
2        James    1 
3        Geena    2 
4        Andy     3
```

I would like to query all my upline, I tried using join but it is not working.

```
select U.userID, U.Name 
from UserAgent U 
inner join UserAgent A 
on A.upline = u.upline
where u.UserID = 4
```

The reason i cant get any record is because i pass 4 as userid therefore it loops until the end of record and not able to join record on top.

What i need is to query all the three of the upline, expected result should be able to get the record of userid 3,2,1

Comment: In your join you ask for rows where the 'upline' column are the same. The example show no rows where this is true. Is it possible to have more than one user id with the same upline value?

Comment: I feel like this example is a bit over-simplified and misleading. If this is a parent/child relationship and the numbers are scattered, you'll want to use a CTE because you need to find your target row and get its parent and its parent and so on.

Comment: @Jay , 1 user only can have 1 up line , but up line may have multiple down line , but the column only store single value .

Comment: Just to make sure I didn't dupe hammer your question too soon - the `upline` column refers to the `UserID` column of a *different* row, right?

Comment: @ZoharPeled yes

Comment: So the duplicate is correct. recursive cte is your friend.